# Get Selected Columns and Table Name from Laravel DBBuilder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i want to get the selected column from a query using DBBuilder, this is the code:

```
    $categoriesQuery =  DB::table('Category')->select('Category.categoryId','Category.categoryName','Category.categoryDescription');
```

and i try o get (for example):

```
    $tableName = $categoriesQuery->getTableName(); //Category
    $selectedColumns = $categoriesQuery->getSelectedColumns(); // ['Category.categoryId','Category.categoryName','Category.categoryDescription']
```

Please, how can i do this with the querybuilder (Not eloquent)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, you do this:

```
$categoriesQuery = DB::table('Category')->select('Category.categoryId','Category.categoryName','Category.categoryDescription');
```

Since here `$categoriesQuery` is Query Builder instance, you can use the `columns` property to get a list of columns:

```
$categoriesQuery->columns
```

And to get table name, use the `from` property:

```
$categoriesQuery->from
```

Comment: thanks, but i need to get only the column names and the table name from the query, not the data from the query. :)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin And what if I want from a eloquent model instance.